# How to make tableview unobscured when there is text in the search bar in swift4

Tags: uitableview, swift4, uisearchcontroller

I have search controller that is in a tableview controller and the code is the following

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ///// color of letter in search index ////
    self.tableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.black
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    //////////// search Controller //////////////
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    //self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Countries"
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true
    self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false



}
```

When I search the search bar the items in the background (list of countries) are inactive as shown in the image and that is fine 
[image]

What I want to do is make the items in background active once there is text in the search bar. I tried the following code but it does not work

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
 {
        if (searchText.count>0)
        {
            self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        }
 }
```

My view controller conforms to UISearchBarDelegate and UISearchResultsUpdating for the info

Comment: in `viewDidLoad` you call `self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true` - set it to false there

Comment: it doesnot work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple doc:

> This property(obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation) controls only
>   whether the original view controller is **initially** obscured.

Apple's suggestion:

> If you use the same view controller to display the searchable content
>   and search results, it is recommended that you set this property to
>   **false**. The default value of this property is true.

you may use tableview's **isUserInteractionEnabled** property instead, make it enabled after user input something.